# ..getHours is not a function

Tags: imacros

i have some trouble with imacros. It seems that it doesn't recognise getHours() or setHours() functions.

I'll post a bit of my code to show you what i'm trying to do:

```
var FormatData = new Date(D[0],D[1]-1,D[2],D[3],D[4],D[5],0);
var Data=FormatData; 
Data.SetHours(Data.getHours() - Durata[0]);
```

After execution , i get this error: ".getHours is not a function, line 22 (Error code: -991)"

If it helps, i received the same kind of error for setTimeout() function. And i solved it by adding window.setTimeout().

I tried the same trick here, but still "window.getHours is not a function, line 22 (Error code: -991)"

If you have a solution for using .setHours in imacros , please repply. 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Don't you need parentheses when trying to call a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this one?

```
Data.setHours(Data.getHours()- Durata[0]);
```

Comment: Sorry i copyied wrong when posted.. The original code was as you said.

Comment: Please note that it should be setHours, not SetHours.

Comment: And "SetHours(), is actualy with lowercas :setHours() , I will try this one , and see if it works

Comment: It seems that this solved the problem. Thanx @burak emre